# Laravel 5 function "latest()" doesn't work, when emails are inserted to database

Tags: php, database, email, laravel-5

I am adding emails through the query in my database:

```
DB::table('email')->insert(['from'=>$from,'body'=>$message,'message_no'=>$message_number]);
```

then i have to display emails which are saved in database. So, for displaying new email on top in display method i have used:

```
$data = Email::latest()->get();
return view('emails.display',compact('data'));
```

But, the new emails are at bottom.
Then i checked in my table in database there is 00.00.00 in 'created_at' column.

My question is what can i do to fill the 'created_at' filed in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the email derectly from the class like so:

```
Email::create(['from'=>$from,'body'=>$message,'message_no'=>$message_number]);
```

And it should fill in created_at and updated_at automaticly

Answer (score 1):

You are making direct insert into DB table (without using Laravel Eloquent) so you have to set time manual..

```
DB::table('email')->insert(['from'=>$from,'body'=>$message,'message_no'=>$message_number, 'created_at'=>\Carbon\Carbon::now()->toRfc822String()]);
```

P.S> Laravel is using this Carbon library to generate time so it should be available for use.